# linux find files under a certer folder and replace string

Tags: linux, find

in order to change the remote gerrit url for all projects, in folder `workspace`, all files named `config` that is under `.git` folder, changes a pattern like `a.b.c` to `x.y.z`.

For shot, find all `workspace > all_folder_under_workspace > .git> config`, and change its content `a.b.c` to `x.y.z`

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `git config --local`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  there is another git remote server. :)

Comment: And? Just change the remote value.

Comment: but I still have to manually step into every project folder and run command

Comment: Sure, but that's a solved problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sure.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, it works but looks very basic.

```
find -name config | grep '.git/config' | xargs sed -i 's/a.b.c/x.y.z/g'
```